# Grep returns sequence of aces instead of the result I expect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, grep

I have a file called threads.log, here is a sample of that file

```
Threads:    40
Threads:    1
Threads:    1
Threads:    3
Threads:    5
Threads:    5
Threads:    1
Threads:    5
// rest
```

I am doing that in terminal:
`echo $(cat threads.log | grep -o [0-9]*)`

This is the output: `1 1 1 1 1 1 1` instead of the expected numbers. Why is that happening?

Comment: Do you have a file named `1` in your current directory?

Comment: not sure but your code works for me. try removing the -o to see what behind the 1

Comment: @ExcelledProducts Run `touch 1` and then try the command again and see what you get.

Comment: i get your output. `1 1 1`

Comment: @ExcelledProducts Exactly. That's shell globbing at work for you. Compare `echo [0-9]*` vs. `echo '[0-9]*'` for a bit more obvious display of what is going on there if you need one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a great many things wrong (or sub-optimal) with this line.

```
echo $(cat threads.log | grep -o [0-9]*)
```

The wrapping `echo` is entirely useless (well it does something but nothing good), remove it.

```
cat threads.log | grep -o [0-9]*
```

There's no need to `cat | grep` grep takes files directly.

```
grep -o [0-9]* threads.log
```

`[0-9]*` is a shell glob. If you have, and I expect you do, a file that starts with a digit in your current directory then the shell will expand `[0-9]*` into the list of matching files and your `grep` will not be getting the arguments you expect. Quote the pattern.

```
grep -o '[0-9]*' threads.log
```

That matches zero digits when it can and produces no output. You want one-or-more digits so use `\+`.

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+' threads.log
```

Comment: I wish I could plus this twice. This is very correct.

Comment: I have to admit to being surprised by that last step a bit. The behaviour of `*` there is a bit odd it to my mind.